# count unique values for each column per ID in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset which is quite big (140000 obs * 125 attributes). Each ob is associated with an ID (which can be unique or not). I want to count unique values for each attribute (columns) per ID.

I tried `aggregate(. ~ ID, mydata, function(x) length(unique(x))`. But it doesn't work. Also given the size of the data frame, I feel even it works it may take too long to do it. Anyone knows a better way to do it?

The dataset:

```
ID  Attr1   Attr2   Attr3   Attr125
1   A   X   Y   123
1   B   Z   Y   345
1   B   X   Y   134
2   A   Z   Y   abc
2   C   Y   Y   def
3   D   Y   N   xyz
4   B   Z   Y   789
```

The result I want:

```
ID  Attr1   Attr2   Attr3   Attr125
1   2   2   1   3
2   2   2   1   2
3   1   1   1   1
4   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: What *didn't work*? I get the desired result with your code (after adding the missing `)` at the end of your `aggregate()` call, which I presume is just a typo in the question). 140,000 rows is not that big (IMHO).

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it like this:

```
dat <- read.table("clipboard", header = T)
library(reshape2)
mdat <- melt(dat, id = "ID")
library(dplyr)
counts <- mdat %>% group_by(ID, variable) %>% summarize(n_unique = length(unique(value)))

> counts
   ID variable n_unique
1   1    Attr1        2
2   1    Attr2        2
3   1    Attr3        1
4   1  Attr125        3
5   2    Attr1        2
6   2    Attr2        2
7   2    Attr3        1
8   2  Attr125        2
9   3    Attr1        1
10  3    Attr2        1
11  3    Attr3        1
12  3  Attr125        1
13  4    Attr1        1
14  4    Attr2        1
15  4    Attr3        1
16  4  Attr125        1
```

Or, reshaping again

```
> dcast(counts, ID ~ variable)
Using n_unique as value column: use value.var to override.
  ID Attr1 Attr2 Attr3 Attr125
1  1     2     2     1       3
2  2     2     2     1       2
3  3     1     1     1       1
4  4     1     1     1       1
```

Another possible `dplyr` solution which doesn't require `melt`ing first:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_each(
    funs(n_distinct))

#   ID Attr1 Attr2 Attr3 Attr125
# 1  1     2     2     1       3
# 2  2     2     2     1       2
# 3  3     1     1     1       1
# 4  4     1     1     1       1
```

Comment: Gregor, I added another `dplyr` possibility. Hope that's fine for you. Cheers.

Comment: @Henrik very nice! Didn't know about `summarise_each`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I hesitated posting this because it is similar to @mgriebe's answer, but this is a different way to use `data.table`. I find  `data.table` is useful for these operations (however, your `aggregate` call worked just fine for me):

```
# Load the data.table package
require( data.table )

# First copy your data.frame to a data.table
dt <- data.table( mydata )

# Count length of ID unique ID values for each column using the .SD operator of data.table
dt[ , lapply( .SD , function(x) length(unique(x)) ) , by=ID , .SDcols=2:5 ]` 
#   ID Attr1 Attr2 Attr3 Attr125
#1:  1     2     2     1       3
#2:  2     2     2     1       2
#3:  3     1     1     1       1
#4:  4     1     1     1       1
```

Remember to adjust the `.SDcols` to the column numbers where your attributes are stored....

Comment: Ah, yes.  I think this is what he is looking for.  Before seeing this answer, I supposed that he wanted to find the number of unique sets of attributes per ID.